# Call a JavaScript function from an HTML element?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to implement initialization via JavaScript similar to Ken Wheeler's Slick Carousel.  Using jQuery you can select an element like this: `$('.carousel-element').slick();`.

Is there any way do something similar using JavaScript?  For example if I have a variable that holds an element, can I use that to call a custom function?

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('example-1');

myElement.customFunction();
```

Thank you in advance!  I was having a lot of trouble figuring out how to word this, so if anyone knows what this technique is called that will help as well.

Comment: Sound like a [x/y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Can you give a example of `customFunction()` to see why you would do this?

Comment: _"Is there any way do something similar using JavaScript"_ jQuery ___is___ JavaScript!

Comment: You would have to add a function to the `Element` prototype that you could then call on any element. I'm not sure whether it would make sense to do this though, it depends upon your use-case.